# Way to fix "missing QuerySet" and "override QuerySet" with Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm trying to code a blog with django but I want to add a placeholder to my form when creating or editing an article. So I had the forms.py because before that I wasn't using a form from this file because I only needed the models.py file. I fount a way to do what I wanted and so add my placeholder into my input from my forms. But one problem, when I updated my website and went to my pages to see the changed an error appeared.[image: the error on the page, it's the same error for my form to create and edit a post]

So I tried to fix the problem by looking on the web and I saw a lot of people having approximately the same problem but the answers were that I had to add a get_queryset definition in my views in views.py for the specific forms. I didn't find what I have to set in the definition of the get_queryset and not very understood where I have to put these definitions. I would be very grateful if you can help me.
Here's my code :

My views in view.py :

```
class BlogHome(ListView):
    model = BlogPost
    context_object_name = "posts"

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return queryset
        else:
            return queryset.filter(published=True)


@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class BlogPostCreate(CreateView):
    form_name = UpdatePostForm

class BlogPostEdit(UpdateView):
    form_name = CreatePostForm
```

My urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('create/', BlogPostCreate.as_view(), name="create"),
    path('edit/<str:slug>/', BlogPostEdit.as_view(), name="edit"),
```

My forms.py :

```
from django import forms
from posts.models import BlogPost

class UpdatePostForm(forms.Form):
    model = BlogPost
    template_name = 'posts/blogpost_edit.html'
    fields = [
        'title',
        'slug',
        'content', 
        'published', 
        'author', 
        'created_on'
    ]

    class Meta:
        title = forms.CharField(
            widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder' : 'Enter the title of the article'}),
        ),
        slug = forms.CharField(
            widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder' : 'Enter the title of the article'}),
        ),
        content = forms.CharField(
            widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder' : 'Enter the title of the article'}),
        ),
        created_on = forms.CharField(
            widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder' : 'Enter the date of creation'}),
        ),

class CreatePostForm(forms.Form):
    model = BlogPost
    template_name = 'posts/blogpost_create.html'
    fields = [
        'title',
        'slug',
        'content', 
        'published', 
        'author', 
        'created_on'
    ]

    class Meta:
        title = forms.CharField(
            widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder' : 'Enter the title of the article'}),
        ),
        slug = forms.CharField(
            widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder' : 'Enter the title of the article'}),
        ),
        content = forms.CharField(
            widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder' : 'Enter the title of the article'}),
        ),
        created_on = forms.CharField(
            widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder' : 'Enter the date of creation'}),
        ),
```

My models.py :

```
from django.contrib .auth import get_user_model
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.urls import reverse

User = get_user_model()


class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, verbose_name="Titre")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_on = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Publié")
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name="Contenu")
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='blog')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']
        verbose_name = "Article"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def author_or_default(self):
        return self.author.username if self.author else "L'auteur inconnu"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:home')
```

Comment: First you can remove @method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch') from the class. Instead you should use `permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]`

Answer (score 0):

```
class BlogPostCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = UpdatePostForm
    template_name = 'update_post.html'
    success_url = 'success'
```

OR

```
class BlogPostCreate(CreateView):
    model = UpdatePost
```

Try the above. Please remove `@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')`  from this class view because its a class view not a method.

Your form should be a model for I expect.

`class CreatePostForm(forms.ModelForm):`

I am updating my answer as per your last comment. [Check this for django modelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/). You need to add a meta in your form:

```
class CreatePostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['...', ....]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I can't use the second option because I need to use my form in forms.py. But for the first option it could be but now I have an other error when I go on these page "**BaseForm.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance**'".

Comment: I updated the answer. You have to make both forms as model form. And if your first problem is solved then kindly accept the answer.

Comment: Now after changing everythings as you told me, I have an error telling me that there is no model class specified in my ModelForm but the first line of them is the "**model = BlogPost**".